# Error with configuring bookdown.org account using bookdown::publish_book() in RStudio

Tags: r, bookdown, rsconnect

When trying to publish a book (for the first time) on bookdown.org using

```
bookdown::publish_book(render = "none")
```

I get the following error message:

```
You do not currently have a bookdown.org publishing account configured on this system.
Would you like to configure one now? [Y/n]: Y
Error in response$token_claim_url : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

It seems that the problem is with

```
rsconnect::connectUser(server = 'bookdown.org')
```

which gives the same error message:

```
Error in response$token_claim_url : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I have tried using my own book project and the demo book project within RStudio "A Minimal Book Example" by Yihui Xie.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

i use this method to solve the problem:
open Rstudio

Manage Account - Connect - RStudio Connect - input: bookdown.org